# Combinations of unknown number $n$

Tags: combinations

> All members of a group play basketball, while all except one play ice hockey. The number of possible basketball teams of $5$ members each is the same as the number of possible ice hockey teams of $6$ members each. How many members are there in the group?

I am unable to derive a formula for the number of teams.

Answer - $15$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to identify your equality. We have
\begin{align*}
 {n\choose5} &= {n-1\choose6} \\
\rightarrow \frac{n!}{5!(n-5)!} &= \frac{(n-1)!}{6!(n-7)!}
\end{align*}

And you can solve for your result $n$ from there with a bit of manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

$n\choose5$=$n-1\choose6$

Solve this equation and you will get it.